# "Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand." Flask login

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am getting the ubiquitous flask wtform 400 error, and have tried other solutions. It let to improvement in my form, but didn't stop the error. I have

templates/register.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2> Welcome to the status page</h2>
    <br>
    <form action="/register" method="post" name="register_user">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <h4>Register</h4>
        <p>
            Email:<br>
            {{ form.email }}<br>
            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                <p><span style="color: red">[{{ error }}]</span></p>
            {% endfor %}
            Password:<br>
            {{ form.password }}<br>
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                <p><span style="color: red">[{{ error }}]</span></p>
            {% endfor %}
            Confirm password:<br>
            {{ form.confirm }}<br>
            {% for error in form.confirm.errors %}
                <p><span style="color: red">[{{ error }}]</span></p>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="register" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
    <p><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Log in</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField, TextField, PasswordField, validators
from wtforms.validators import Required


class RegistrationForm(Form):
    # name = TextField('Your name', [validators.Length(min=2, max=60)])
    email = TextField('Email Address', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    password = PasswordField('New Password', [
        validators.Required(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')
```

the views.py:

```
    @application.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def register():
        form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
        print(form)
        print(form.email.data)
        print(form.password.data)
        print(form.confirm.data)
        print(form.validate())
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            user = User(email=form.email.data, password=form.password.data)
            user.save()
            flash('Thanks for registering')
            return redirect(url_for('awaiting_approval'))
        return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

the prints look like

```
<app.forms.RegistrationForm object at 0x7ff762e11790>
fakeguy@fake.org
123456
1234
False
```

exactly like I expected. I assumed I would get a re-rendering of the page with an error message of 'Passwords must match' based on the validator of the `password` field. What can I do to let this form fail and rerender page? Thank you

Comment: you have a number of url_for statements in the code. do you have the appropriate functions in the views.py module and are they registered correctly?

Answer (score 1):

register.html:

```
<form action="{{url_for('register')}}" </form>
```

when you submit the form, url_for will look at your views.py for `register` function.
second thing you must have a function named: `awaiting_approval` because you are redirect this view function after post was successfully.